# Access Applications directory in Terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line

I'm really new to command line and I'm trying to access my Applications directory within Terminal.

By default, I am stuck in my user directory but Applications is a child of the "Macintosh HD".

Any tips on how to get to this directory as opposed to username>Applications?

Comment: A great tutorial is http://linuxcommand.org/learning_the_shell.php. It's what I learned the shell on, and I enjoyed it thoroughly.

Answer (score 62):

In the Terminal you can type the *absolute path*...

```
cd /Applications
```

to access applications installed for all users.

If you want to access the root folder (named "Macintosh HD", in your case), it called `/` in Mac OS X (and other UNIX variants).

And `cd`, meaning **c**hange **d**irectory, is used to navigate.

---

Alternatively, you can use the shortcut <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> in the Finder and type...

```
/Applications
```

You do not need to type out the whole name. [Tab-completion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_completion) automatically adds the last letters. You can invoke tab-completion by pressing <kbd>⇥</kbd> while typing `/Applications`.

Comment: You can also drag the applications folder from the Finder into the Terminal window which will automatically insert the path.

Comment: @jaberg Yeah, but only in Lion, right?

Comment: It goes back way before Lion, but I can't remember exactly when that feature was added. 10.4?

Answer (score 6):

In terminal type:

```
cd /
cd Applications
```

Or you can just type:

```
cd /Applications
```

At this point, if you type `pwd` *(print working directory)* it should return `/Applications`

A great place to start with Terminal is http://linuxcommand.org/learning_the_shell.php even though it is aimed at Linux users

Answer (score 3):

To navigate using the terminal you will use 2 commands; `cd` and `ls`.

To change directory you use `cd`. Ex: `cd myfolder/anotherFolder`.

You can type `pwd` to display the current directory you are in.

To list the content of a directory use `ls`. You can get more info about the content of a directory using `ls -al`.

You will notice that here are 2 directories which are always present wherever you list the content of a directory: `.` and `..`.

`.` is simply a reference to the current directory so typing `cd ./somedir` and `cd somedir` are equivalent.

`..` is a reference to the parent directory. So using `cd ..` will move you back to the parent directory.

There are 2 ways to navigate. Either by using the full path or by using the relative path.

Let's say you are in `/Users/user20378`. If you want to get to /Applications you can either navigate there using the full path `cd /Application` or the relative path `cd ../../Applications`.

Depending on where you want to navigate the relative path can be more or less efficient than the full path.

Use tab while typing the name of a folder or a file to auto complete.

Comment: I would split these up into paragraphs for each idea.

Answer (score 1):

The terminal app supports drag and drop if you are more comfortable in Finder.

The `cd` command of course changes the current directory to the one to type or paste / drop.

So type `cd` in terminal and then drag in the correct Applications folder from finder shortcut, from a save dialog or a finder window into the terminal window with your mouse and let go.